# Store Locator with Product Filtering Geolocation

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps, store

Hi I am new to development. I am wondering how the database would be structured?

I will have a table for all the store with their addresses, hours, lat/lng, emails. But what about the products? Each store will have multiple products and the user will be able to enter the product on a search input, the stores will be listed and the googlemap will mark all of them.

My question is, should the products be on a seperate table joined with the stores table? If so, should each product be on it's own column like product1, product2, etc? They will need to be connected with the stores.

Comment: You may find it helpful to read about database normalization as you begin this software design task. You probably want a `store` table, a `product` table, and a `product_store` join table relating them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make 3 tables. Product, Shop and the third (Product_Shop) to connect these two tables since you have a m:n (many to many) relationship.

A product can be placed into multiple shops and a shop can contain multiple products. Example: (a shop called tesco can contain products like: milk, juice.., and milk can be located in a shop called tesco, sainsbury, Mark and spencer ect.)

Because of that you need the "connection" table. If you want to learn more, there are loads of explanations on line. Just google: "database relationships"

Here is an example of that, if you want to add more attributes (columns), then do so.

Basic tables and connections:[image]

To connect your database with google maps I suggest to read the following (always refer to the documentation first):

URL:https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3